# OpenStack networking to access internet

Tags: networking, openstack

I have installed OpenStack Grizzly on a single node.

I have two network interfaces:

```
external connection (eth0)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:b5:35:3c
          inet addr:10.35.141.242 Bcast:10.35.141.255 Mask:255.255.255.128
          [...]
          RX bytes:4763669 (4.7 MB)  TX bytes:3566739 (3.5 MB)

internal connection (eth1)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:b5:35:3d
          inet addr:192.168.20.10  Bcast:192.168.20.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          [...]
          RX bytes:122430862 (122.4 MB)  TX bytes:46150 (46.1 KB)
```

I am using Linux bridge, linuxbridge_conf.ini:

```
[VLANS]
tenant_network_type = vlan
network_vlan_ranges = physnet1:1000:2999
sql_connection = mysql://quantum:quantum@localhost/quantum
reconnect_interval = 2

[LINUX_BRIDGE]
physical_interface_mappings = physnet1:eth1

[AGENT]
polling_interval = 2

[SECURITYGROUP]
firewall_driver = quantum.agent.linux.iptables_firewall.IptablesFirewallDriver
```

I have created an internal network (192.168.0.0/24). Created a router and attached it to the network. The router IP is 192.168.0.1, but after creating a VM in this network, I am not able to ping the router from the VM as well as the host machine on which OpenStack is installed—but I am able to ping the DHCP server of the network. The DHCP server IP is 192.168.0.2.

The ns-XXXXXX interface that is created also gets the IP 192.168.0.2. Is it the DHCP server? Should there be another interface that should be created for the internal subnet router? I installed using CloudGear (https://github.com/ilearnstack/cloudgear).

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you want to check first

1. Is your VM getting IP. Check by logging into the console not from the dashboard.
2. Did you create your external bridge interface? If so did you add the physical port to your bridge interface.
3. Also check your security rules. Make sure you have the "ping" rule added to the security group on which your VM is using.
4. Does your network-map view look right?

Answer (score 0):

The VM needs to have a floating IP assigned to it. http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/cli-manage-ip-addresses.html